# How do I create a panel of buttons with a simple divider line, or no dividers, in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface

This seems like a really basic task, but after a lot of searching and research, still haven't found a clear answer.  I found GridView, but not sure this is how you're supposed to do it.

I've found several apps that have UI elements similar to what I need, for example the top buttons of the android market.

[image: here's an example of what I'm talking about]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That can easily be accomplished with a horizontal `LinearLayout` that contains a set of Buttons or ImageButtons. The rest is just styling.

See [Hello Linear Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html) to get started.

Comment: One way you can do the dividers, is just add a View with a 1px width, and a background color of your choice, in between the items in the layout.

Comment: That makes sense now.  I'm not a UI designer and so far I've been frustrated trying to make things look "right" with Android layouts.  Of course CSS is a pain too...